# How to get the final url from google search result in PHP

Tags: php, url, redirect, search-engine

Using PHP how do I get the final url destination from Google search result? For example

I want to get

```
http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/start/whats-new-in-windows-phone
```

from

```
http://www.google.com.my/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.windowsphone.com%2Fen-us%2Fhow-to%2Fwp8%2Fstart%2Fwhats-new-in-windows-phone&ei=U0-vUa7HDseOrQenzIGIAg&usg=AFQjCNE7USUy5FcCHAIPreZ7UXBCQ8JUcg&sig2=NwHO-_b51du7XRiknzniXA&bvm=bv.47380653,d.bmk
```

**UPDATE**

So far I've tried the following but it does not work for Google search result links

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("http://www.google.com.my/url?sa=t&etc...");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$header = "Location: ";
$pos = strpos($response, $header);
$pos += strlen($header);
$redirect_url = substr($response, $pos, strpos($response, "\r\n", $pos)-$pos);
echo $redirect_url;
?>
```

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: What is your problem: get page with results and find url (google can send different results for humans and programs) - or - cut out string `http://www.windowsphone.com...` from string `http://www.google.com.my/url...` ?

Comment: I wanted to do it automatically. I am creating a browser app so google will send results for humans.

Comment: amh guys do you think the "/en-us/how-to/wp8/start/" are directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this. Little less code. No foreach needed.

```
$url = "http://www.google.com.my/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.windowsphone.com%2Fen-us%2Fhow-to%2Fwp8%2Fstart%2Fwhats-new-in-windows-phone&ei=U0-vUa7HDseOrQenzIGIAg&usg=AFQjCNE7USUy5FcCHAIPreZ7UXBCQ8JUcg&sig2=NwHO-_b51du7XRiknzniXA&bvm=bv.47380653,d.bmk";

$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY );
parse_str($query, $link);

echo $link["url"];
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just trying to extract and decode part of an address, from within another address.

Try this:

```
$url = "http://www.google.com.my/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.windowsphone.com%2Fen-us%2Fhow-to%2Fwp8%2Fstart%2Fwhats-new-in-windows-phone&ei=U0-vUa7HDseOrQenzIGIAg&usg=AFQjCNE7USUy5FcCHAIPreZ7UXBCQ8JUcg&sig2=NwHO-_b51du7XRiknzniXA&bvm=bv.47380653,d.bmk"
$parsed = parse_url($url);
$args = explode('&',$parsed['query']);
foreach($args as $arg) {
    list($name,$val) = explode('=',$arg,2);
    if($name !== 'url') continue;
    $url = urldecode($val);
    break;
}
echo $url;
```